# Exemptions from wearing a face covering

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom, sickness, furlough

I was made exempt from wearing a mask by my doctor. I have a letter. However my employer has stated that there are no exceptions and sent me home.

They said I would be on sick pay, however because I was off with Cancer I don't have sick pay left.

If they sent me home should they not pay me?

Also now we are locked down again, I am clinically vulnerable, so shielding, my work have told me that they can not furlough me as we are front line workers.

Comment: Sorry to hear your employer is being unhelpful, but this isn't something we can help with - you need to talk to a lawyer or similar.

Comment: Your employer has a duty to protect your co-workers. You could offer wearing a face shield, or think about how bad wearing a mask is for you.

Comment: if you've expanded SSP already you should look into applying for ESA. It specifically has provisions for someone who must be shielding: https://www.gov.uk/employment-support-allowance/eligibility

though I am not sure how exactly did your doctor clear you to go and work (knowing nature of it and need of having to do it in person), but also told you to not mask. That doesn't add up.

Comment: FWIW, I was under the impression that employers have, basically, the right to furlough people for any pandemic-related reason whatsoever.

Comment: I'm assuming the us but for legal questions it helps to include your location.

Comment: As someone who is shielding you **are** [eligible to be furloughed](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/check-which-employees-you-can-put-on-furlough-to-use-the-coronavirus-job-retention-scheme#if-your-employees-health-has-been-affected-by-coronavirus-covid-19-or-any-other-conditions).. but only if your employer chooses to do so. Otherwise SSP or [ESA](https://www.gov.uk/employment-support-allowance/eligibility) if the SSP allowance has been used up are options.

Comment: I'd vote to reopen this question if it had some sort of specific question to it that we could answer. Right now, it just appears to be a complaint and nothing we can do about this. We also need location as laws may protect you if you have a medical waiver. Please rephrase this so it has a question, location, and what sort of thing you'd like us to help with.

Comment: I have added tags based on your profile and content of your question. If you don't think they apply, please correct them.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately even after considering your medical situation I am inclined to agree with your employer. Since the mask is used as a protection against Covid-19, not using it will put all your co-workers at risk. They may even need to shut down completely depending on the structure of your office.

<strike>As gnasher729 said in the comments, you can offer to use a face shield if possible.</strike> (It turns out using a face shield without mask won't give much of protection (to your co-workers). Thanks @peter).

You can request for remote work if it's possible.

If the above is not possible, all I can recommend is to register as unemployed and try to move into a job which allow remote working.

Comment: Please don't suggest face shields, they are completely ineffective. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: @Peter face shields were suggested first by gnasher above - was that a different one?

Comment: @SolarMike: Someone deleted their comment.

Comment: @Peter Gnashers comment is still there...

Comment: Thanks @Peter, answer updated.